# I am unable to pay the heavy amount of custom duty - now what will happen to that parcel?

Tags: india

There is one parcel I wish to send from Lebanon weighing 87 kg for which Customs is asking for INR 125,000 (~USD 2k) in duty.

I don't have this amount, what will happen now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mail, not travel.

Comment: Sometimes you can pay to have it shipped back to the country of origin.

Answer (score 2):

Custom rules are different in different countries and you'll have look for your countries custom clearance rules.
For most of the countries, in such situation, where there's no one to claim the package (claim = paying custom duty), such packages are auctioned to general public.
The probable best solution would be to wait for the next custom auction in your country where you can get this package for a lower duty.

I hope this helps.